# Destination in WoS invoice is not WoS node

Tags: lightning-network, invoices, bolt11, wallet-of-satoshi

When I create an invoice in Wallet of Satoshi / Android, and `lncli decodepayreq --pay_req=lnbc2` the invoice, there's a destination

```
{
    "destination": "0324ba2392e25bff76abd0b1f7e4b53b5f82aa53fddc3419b051b6c801db9e2247",
```

That's not the WoS node, it's a node called kappa.

Why is that?

Comment: Could it be that WoS uses multiple nodes to manage their customers' funds, and "kappa" is just one of them?

Comment: Then I would expect the ppm to be zero, but it's 500?

Comment: Or is it kind of hidden income model?